# React setState() not working properly in multiple smart components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I am having issues while changing state.
I have one signin page which changes state to home when a user signed in but when I click on any navigation option it is changing state and displaying content but going back to signin component. Help if you have the reason. I've been stuck on this for 3 hrs.

[Screenshot of code]

Comment: Post some code too.Without it won't be able to understand.

Comment: on Stack Overflow, "we feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them" :)

Comment: Where are you setting your state? In which component?